# DevTools was disconnected from the page, electron

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

Guys i need to open some web application into my electron app, i used `<webview>` tag but [official docs][1] of electron offers to use `BrowserView`.
so i used `BrowserView`, BUT i got DevTools was disconnected from the page error! 
simply i need DevTools for my `BrowserView` not my entire app. what should i do?

myCode: just `main.js`

```
const {app, BrowserView, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let win;
let view;
app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    });
    view = new BrowserView({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        }
    });
    win.setBrowserView(view);
    view.setBounds({x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600});
    view.webContents.loadURL('https://example.com');
    win.openDevTools();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`openDevTools`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsopendevtoolsoptions) is basically a function of `webContents` (when used on `BrowserWindow` it's only [redirected](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v4.0.7/lib/browser/api/browser-window.js#L156))

So you can open devtools of main window with

```js
win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

And for the `BrowserView` with

```js
view.webContents.openDevTools()
```

Comment: `{ devTools: true }` is the default and doesn't open them, just enables them (so you can use `openDevTools()`)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you open DevTools without giving an HTML (or some valid URL) file to the current window.

When you start your application you need to load an HTML file to the window before use `toggleDevTools`. Solve it by using for example `mainWindow.loadUrl('url to an html file or some url')` after you build mainWindow using `BrowserWindow()`. You tried to open DevTools on the `win` window but it has no URL defined, so it is just an Electron window with anything inside of this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue.. not sure whats the exact error but in my case my model was returning null. I changed that to some value and handled using jquery which resolved my problem.

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand ! And if possible add your tried code so we can help.